# How to check the data present in data base and the data from body are same or not? mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I want to check a condition if the data from database and data from body are same or not before executing update API in nest js.

Controller.ts

```
  public updateUser = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response | void> => {
    try {
        if (req.body.UserId!='') {
            let results = await this.ServicesService.updateUser(req.params._id, req.body);
            if (results != false) {
                this.success(res, 'Updated Successfully', 200, results._id);
            }
        } 
        return await this.error(res, 'Something Went Wrong!.', 500);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
}
```

service.ts

```
    public async updateUser(_id: any, data: any): Promise<any | Error> {
    try {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {...data }, (err: any, success: any) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                if (!success) {
                    resolve(false);
                } else {
                    resolve(success);
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('service error\n', e);
        throw e;
    }
};
```

How to achive this,any one can suggest either nest js or node js.Thank you...

Comment: You have this text in question "data from body". Which "body" are referring to?

Comment: from front-end fields,you can take any example of your own

Comment: @problrm_solver You have got a problem, you must specify what you trying to do or what have you tried. You are posting questions with just 2 lines and asking someone else to assume? Please add what you want to achieve, don't keep us guessing.

Comment: added the update code plz check

Comment: Just execute your update, if both the data are same, there will practically be no change in the database. For schema validation you can checkout JOI node package

Comment: I know,if both the data are same, there will practically be no change in the database but I want to check bothe the data how can i check